# Topendialog not displaying file extensions

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

This problem only occurs on applications that were previously designed under Delphi 7 and migrated to Delphi 2007 running on WinXP.

I tried for ages to get this problem sorted with no luck.

As far as I am aware, the Topendialog is a Win32 dialog wrapper and it should inherit the windows folder options which, in my case, is set to show the file extensions of all files.

Now, if I create a new application and drop a Topendialog on it, when it runs, it shows the file extensions as expected.

If I drop the same dialog onto an existing application and run, it doesn't show the file extensions.

If fact if I write a filename string into the filename property before calling the dialog a la 'Myfile.txt', when the dialog is displayed the filename is shown as 'Myfile', the extension doesn't show and neither do any files in the list.

Has anyone else seem this behaviour?

Anybody have any workarounds?

Edit: Images uploaded to shown differences between Topendialog on a new project and existing project.

[image: As shown on new project]

[image: As shown on existing project]

Comment: I'm not sure if that might be related, but... "D7 migrated to D2007" might hint to a difference regarding Windows themes. Do you have a manifest in your application (via XPMan or "Enable runtime themes" in the project options)?

Comment: What happens if you drop `TOpenDialog` on a newly created Form in  your existing Application? What happens if you create a `TOpenDialog` object at runtime?

Comment: @Andy k: It would be somewhat helpful if you posted screenshots illustrating the issue. (The open dialogs can look a bit different depending on a lot of factors. That might help to determine the issue, which, honestly, sounds very strange to me...)

Comment: @Ulriich originally the applications were created using D7 on a win2000 machine. On migration I dropped an XPmanifest component on the mainform which enabled XP themes.

Comment: @splash I tried both of these and the behaviour is the same, no file extensions shown.

Comment: You have everything you need to work this out. You can work it out. It's exceptionally hard for us to work it out. Why do I say that? Because you have a reproduction. Simply remove parts of the misbehaving app until you have something identical to the vanilla app. Somewhere along the way the behaviour will change. At that point you'll know what determines the behaviour. Also, why are you using the lame legacy dialogs rather than the nice new Vista file dialogs?

Comment: Copy the OpenDialog from your application into WinMerge (it will be pasted as plain text in dfm format), then copy a new TOpenDialog from your test application (the one that works) on the other side so you can compare them. Maybe you'll find a property value that differs between them that might trigger this behaviour.

Comment: @david. Haha My machine had vista installed when I bought it, I downgraded to XP because Vista ran like a dog.... a very slow dog.

Comment: Ah, I thought they were the legacy dialogs on Vista. But they are actually the XP dialogs. They make me feel sick.

Comment: In the two pics, even the left shortcut part is different, is it from the same computer?

Comment: @justmade My apps all update the places bar with short cuts to the applications data directories. It makes no difference if I don't change the places bar. Another thing I tried was deleting all the Delphi peripheral files that relate to the project, files like dproj,dof, ddp,dcu,dsk and the like, still no joy. Its baffling me.

Comment: Have you tried making a new simple program using D7 and then port it to D2007 to see the effect?  Maybe you can try to use SHGetSettings(ShellFlags, SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS); for a test of Show Extension Settings in your application.  http://www.delphigroups.info/2/d8/409429.html

Comment: Start by removing the `XPManifest` component (and `XPMan` from the uses clause), and then go into `Project|Options|Application` and check 'Enable runtime themes' instead.

Comment: @Ken tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: Did you compare the .DFM content for the two forms (the part that has the OpenDialog info) to see if there were any significant differences? (Right-click the form, choose `View As Text`, and search for `OpenDialog`.)

Comment: @Justmade, thanks for that tip, didn't know about that system function. I ran it on existing application and returns 0 on a new app it returns 2, ie the fShowExtensions bit is set. This means the RTL is enabling 'hide file extensions for known types' on my old apps but not on new.

Comment: @ken White Yeah, I already checked that. The dfm shows nothing at all..  ` object OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog
    Left = 224
    Top = 280
  end

  object OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog
    Left = 480
    Top = 240
  end `

Comment: @Andy How did you conclude that the RTL is doing that? You already said you were messing with the places bar. What else are you doing? Problem almost certainly in your code. Too easy just to blame the RTL.

Comment: @david Using the SHGetSettings query shows that the flag is wrong before any of my code is called and before any components get initialized. what else can I conclude?

Comment: @Andyk, that's impossible. Both images above show a filter, which doesn't exist unless you're assigning it. Therefore, there either has to be more in the .dfm or you're doing something in your code that you're not showing/telling us. Please edit your post and show what you're doing (post actual code). This back-and-forth in comments to get bits and pieces of info isn't working (and isn't how SO is designed to work). And just as a note: if it were the RTL's fault, others would have posted about this issue either here or at EMBT's forums, or logged a bug at QC. None of those exist - not the RTL.

Comment: Oh, I had not realised that you check this at app startup.

Comment: @ken Yes the file filters, initial directories etc are set in the program since the dialog is used more than once with different file filter types. But there is no Topendialog settings exposed by the vcl which can change the way file extensions are displayed. If there were, I wouldn't be here. I agree with you this isn't really getting anywhere but I posted here on the hope that someone would pipe up with a 'oh yeah I had that problem and solve it by....'. Obviously it's not that simple, if it was, I would have solved it by myself.

Comment: My only idea: Copy only the .dpr, .dfm, .res, and .pas files (note no .dproj file) from your project into a new folder. Start Delphi, and use File|Open Project, navigate to that new folder, and open the .dpr file. Delphi will create a new project. Go to Project|Options and set any special library paths needed to get your app to build. Does the problem disappear?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have a workaround for this problem.

It turns out that calling SHGetSettings in the right place actually stops the problem from occurring.

So the workaround is to put it in the project source right at the start.

eg

> program Blah;
>
> uses
>
> Forms,shlobj,
>
> blah,
>   ....   etc
>
> {$R *.TLB}
>
> {$R *.RES}
>
> var ShellFlags:TShellFlagState;
>
> begin
>   SHGetSettings(ShellFlags,SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS);   .....

I have no idea why this makes it work, it shouldn't make any difference as its only a query but it works.

So, thanks to Justmade for suggesting that API call.